# EventHandler Design Practices

Tags: c#, events

I've read that one benefit to the `MyEventHandler`/`MyEventArgs` model is that it allows standard event handlers to handle a variety of events. It sounds good, but perhaps I'm understanding how this is supposed to work. I have the following code:

```
public delegate void DataArrivalEventHandler
    (object sender, DataArrivalEventArgs e);

public class DataArrivalEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DateTime Arrival { get; protected set; }

    public DataArrivalEventArgs()
    {
        Arrival = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public DataArrivalEventArgs(DateTime arrival)
    {
        Arrival = arrival;
    }
}
```

...

```
_pipeReader.DataArrival += new EventHandler(Pipe_DataArrival);
```

...

```
private void Pipe_DataArrival(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

The code throws an error when I'm trying to add the event handler, however, saying that it cannot implicity cast `DataArrivalEventHandler` to `EventHandler`. Changing `DataArrivalEventHandler(Pipe_DataArrival)` to `EventHandler(Pipe_DataArrival)` fixes the problem, so I feel like you should be able to add generic event handlers to more specific events (I understand why you can't do it the other way around.)

Is how I have it the best way to do it, or is there a better convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've got it is right.

There's no conversion from a more specific delegate type to a more general one - but there *is* a conversion from a *method group* with a more specific set of parameters to a delegate type with a more general set of parameters. (It works the other way for return types.)

Now C# 4 changes this slightly, as there *is* a conversion from (say) `Action<string>` to `Action<object>` - but this *only* happens for generic delegates, in terms of their type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think delegate contravariance (assigning EventHandler delegate to DataArrivalEventHandler)  does not work in .NET 1.1. It is available since .NET 2.0

(Your code looks like .NET 1.1 code)

Answer (score 0):

**Naming**

There are a naming convention for events. In your case the event should be named DataArrived. Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0eyck3s(v=VS.71).aspx

**Delegates**

You got two delegates for events that should be used: EventHandler and EventHandler<T>

**Multihtreading**

If you are using multithreading, init your event in the following way.

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> = delegate {};
```

In this way you don't have to worry about multithreading issues.